# Injecting ManagedExecutorService in spring application

Tags: java, spring, javax

I want to use ManagedExecutorService in spring application. However spring is not able to inject it. Getting below error.

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=,
>   description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class
>   java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}

**UPDATE**

I update the code  source code as below to inject ManagedExecutorService.

```
@Bean(name = "commonRestThreadExecutor")
    public ManagedExecutorService commonRestThreadExecutor() throws NamingException {
        return (ManagedExecutorService) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutorService");
    }

 @Autowired
    private ManagedExecutorService commonRestThreadExecutor;
```

But now I am getting below error

> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name >
>   [DefaultManagedExecutorService] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find >
>   [DefaultManagedExecutorService].

Comment: In order to be eligible for injecting, your `ManagedExecutorService` needs to be defined first. How exactly you defined it? And how are you referring to it in the place of expected injection? Please post source code.

Comment: @Gergely Bacso i have added the code

Answer (score 0):

Following declaration resolved mine,

```
@Resource(name = "default", lookup = "java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default")
  private ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;
```